Displaying the Result of Your Nested Color Code
My project code is quite large and tedious, so I've written a shorter code to better explain my problem.
First, please review the following code:


  function chgrad() {
    // Get the selected radio button
    var selectedRadio = document.querySelector('input[name="radioGroup"]:checked');
  
    // Get colors and rotation values
    var red1 = document.getElementById('red1').value;
    var green1 = document.getElementById('green1').value;
    var blue1 = document.getElementById('blue1').value;
  
    var red2 = document.getElementById('red2').value;
    var green2 = document.getElementById('green2').value;
    var blue2 = document.getElementById('blue2').value;
  
    var rot = document.getElementById('rot').value;
  
    // Set background-size to cover before setting background-image
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
  
    // Create gradient string based on selected radio button
    var gradientString;
    if (selectedRadio.value === 'option1') {
      gradientString = "-webkit-linear-gradient(" + rot + "deg, rgb(" + red1 + "," + green1 + "," + blue1 + "))";
    } else if (selectedRadio.value === 'option2') {
      gradientString = "-webkit-linear-gradient(" + rot + "deg, rgb(" + red1 + "," + green1 + "," + blue1 + "), rgb(" + red2 + "," + green2 + "," + blue2 + "))";
    }
  
    // Apply the gradient
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.backgroundImage = gradientString;
  }
 .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: transparent;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper"></div>

    <div class="btn-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioGroup" value="option1" checked>
        <label for="radio1">One colors</label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioGroup" value="option2">
        <label for="radio2">Two colors</label>
    </div>

    <div class="rotate-change-main">
        <label for="rot">Rotate</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="360" oninput="chgrad()" value="0" id="rot">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="range_color1" class="range-color">
        <label for="red1">Red</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" oninput="chgrad();" id="red1" value="0" /><br />
        <label for="green1">Green</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" oninput="chgrad();" id="green1" value="0" /><br />
        <label for="blue1">Blue</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" oninput="chgrad();" id="blue1" value="0" /><br />
    </div>

    <br>

    <div id="range_color2" class="range-color">
        <label for="red2">Red</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" oninput="chgrad();" id="red2" value="0" /><br />
        <label for="green2">Green</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" oninput="chgrad();" id="green2" value="0" /><br />
        <label for="blue2">Blue</label>
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" oninput="chgrad();" id="blue2" value="0" /><br />
    </div>



Problem:
As you can see in the code above, when the first button (One colors) with the ID #radio1 is active, changing the values in the #range_color1 box does not cause any changes in the black box. However, as soon as the second button (Two colors) with the ID #radio2 is activated, a combined color is correctly created.
My question:
My problem is exactly here!
I want the changes to be reflected in the black box in full width (so that there is only one color) when the first button (One colors) with the ID #radio1 is active, and the color to be combined (gradient) when the second button (Two colors) with the ID #radio2 is activated In the black box, a color should be displayed as a combination (gradient).
Additional Information:
I have already tried setting the background-image property to none in the CSS for the .wrapper class. I have also tried creating a separate gradient string for each option, but this does not work either.
I would appreciate it if you could help me solve this problem.
Thank you for your time and assistance.

You should use two color parameters in the if block of the code. If you don't want to use color as the second argument, then you should use "transparent" as the second color. In your case, you can use the same color again in another part of the linear gradient. You need to remove the property "background-color: #000;" from the wrapper class, then the second part will be transparent.
if (selectedRadio.value === 'option1') {
  gradientString = "-webkit-linear-gradient(" + rot + "deg, rgb(" + red1 + "," + green1 + "," + blue1 + "),rgb(" + red1 + "," + green1 + "," + blue1 + "))";
} else if (selectedRadio.value === 'option2') {
  gradientString = "-webkit-linear-gradient(" + rot + "deg, rgb(" + red1 + "," + green1 + "," + blue1 + "), rgb(" + red2 + "," + green2 + "," + blue2 + "))";
}

CSS
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
/*background-color: #000;*/
background-image: transparent;
}


Hi. Still, the color of the first part only takes half of the box! It should cover the entire box when the first button is active.

Hi, instead of using 'transparent' in the if block, replace it with 'rgb(" + red1 + "," + green1 + "," + blue1 + ")'.

Thank you very much for your answer. But is this simple method enough? No need for more scripting? If this is the answer, please update the code so I can accept your answer.

I have edited my response, you can check it, I hope everything is fine now.
